# RxSwift UIBarButtonItem Tap Event Not Called

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have the following code and it DOES not call the Tap event.

```
  self.addNewItemBarButton.rx.tap.subscribe {
            print("button is clicked") // NOT GETTING CALLED!
        }.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

SOLUTION:

```
 self.addNewItemBarButton!.rx.tap.subscribe { _ in
            print("button is clicked") // NOW THIS WORKS
        }.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```